# Why is this grep command not coming back with anything? (Bash)

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have a text file 'samp' that I want to grep ONLY lines that start and end with uppercase vowels.

Using "`grep ^[AEIOU] samp`" works.
Using "`grep [AEIOU]$ samp`" works as well.

But when trying to combine them to "`grep ^[AEIOU]$ samp`" it returns nothing.

3 things:

- Yes, I have lines that start and end with uppercase vowels in samp.
- Yes, I tried every combination of quotes I could think of.  Nothing still.
- Yes, I'm new to unix.

Comment: This is more of a superuser type question.

Comment: @cletus , though grep is the tool, the question really centers around regular expressions (and how well various greps understand PCRE).

Comment: ^=start of line, [AEIOU]=1 character of that set, $=end of line. Do you have any lines that contain only A, E, I, O or U?

Comment: I took out the NPR and BOS tags though I'm of two minds about it. grep and all the other tools are *frequently* used in bash programs, not just as command from the command line and I'd rather give the benefit of the doubt.

Answer (score 8):

What you are giving is a grep for lines that are exactly 1 capital vowel.

Try this:

```
 <cmd> | grep '[AEIOU]$' | grep '^[AEIOU]'
```

I'm sure it can be done using one grep, but I don't know the unix grep very well.  If the regex is like perl it would be

```
 <cmd> | grep '^[AEIOU](.*[AEIOU])?$'
```

Comment: I added quotes so that bash wouldn't try to process the brackets and $ signs. Also prefer the first since grep is quite often faster for simple REs (even if two processes are running).

Comment: Agreed, *nix specializes in piping output through programs like that anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern allows for exactly one vowel on the line. Try:

```
grep ^[AEIOU].*[AEIOU]$
```

Note that this will not now match lines with a single vowel, if you need that too then we  need to get a bit cleverer and use some "or"s.

Comment: only problem with this is that it won't match a line with exactly 1 captical vowel on it.

Answer (score 1):

Your "combined" example is looking for lines that consist of a SINGLE uppercase vowel on a line!  What you wanted is:

```
grep '^[AIOUE].*[AIOUE]$' samp
```

Comment: @scrible As @tster points out on another answer, your regex won't match a line with exactly 1 capital vowel on it.

Answer (score 0):

In discussing *grep*, the 1st edition of Mastering Regular Expressions by Jeffrey Friedl has a "Superficial Survey of a Few Common Programs' Flavor" in Table 6-1 on page 182.

He says "even something as simple as *grep* varies widely"

The regular expressions in *grep* are NOT the same as Perl.

Even *egrep* with extended regular expressions is not the same, but I find it easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

This will match a line that consists only of any number of capital vowels (this includes zero, so it matches blank lines):

```
grep '^[AEIOU]*$'
```

This matches lines that consist only of one or more capital vowels (does not match blank lines):

```
grep -E '^[AEIOU]+$'
```

Either of these will match a line that consists of only one capital vowel.

Answer (score 0):

Using egrep you could do something like:

```
echo $'hello\nworld' | egrep '^h|d$'
```